# How to get next scheduled trigger time programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

I make a new installable trigger that fires each 2 days for my spreadsheet programmatically. Then when I return to the spreadsheet, can I get the next time it will trigger a function? Or even how often it triggers? All I see is that I can get it's type, function it triggers, unique ID and so on.

Thanks

Comment: is this for Appengine or Google Apps script ?

Comment: It's for Apps script. Wrong tag, I'll change it.

Comment: What I usually do is to let my triggered script write the date and time in a cell in the first row of my spreadsheet. This way I see immediately when it was last executed. Simple and efficient :-)

Comment: I thought about writing in the spreadsheet too, but I wanted first to see if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for checking when a trigger will next run or even when it last ran. What you can do however is record when a trigger runs as part of your trigger function. Depending on your application, you can then store the value in a spreadsheet (or better yet use [Properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/)) and then compare this value to the current date/time to generate "Next trigger at..."

This essentially accomplishes the same functionality without having to call a trigger method.

Comment: I can't even see what's the period of the trigger? Is it every 2 days or every 5 minutes?

Comment: You may be able to use the `getEventType()` which returns an Enum EventType. Take a look at these [trigger methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger). It's worth noting that installable triggers can only be seen by the person who installed them.