# Get execution time of trigger in Google Apps Script programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

How do I get the next execution of a certain trigger in GAS? I checked the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers) and also tried debugging via the editor but this option does not seem to exist. Let's say I create a simple time-based trigger and save the trigger Id:

```
var newTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("testFunction")
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(10)
        .onMonthDay(1)
        .create()
        .getUniqueId();
```

Assuming the trigger is at [0] I can check for the ID but I am not able to check the execution time.

```
ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0].getUniqueId(newTrigger);
```

Is this possible? I could enter the following methods from `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0]` but could not find the execution time:

```
toString,
getTriggerSource,
getTriggerSourceId,
isDisabled,
getUniqueId,
getHandlerFunction,
getEventType,
Symbol(__GS_INTERNAL_remote_object_name_),
Symbol(__GS_INTERNAL_remote_object_ref_id_),
Symbol(__GS_INTERNAL_remote_object_server_id_)
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31007128/11225291

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get next scheduled trigger time programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007128/how-to-get-next-scheduled-trigger-time-programmatically)